# mongoose find query $in giving priority for specific item

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query the Mongodb using following mongoose query. And I want to give priority for specific brand and get the inventories of that brand first. How can I give priority for specific brand and get those results first rather than other brands.

```
db.inventory.find( { brand: { $in: [ 'brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3' ] } } )
```

Comment: Do you have any value or reference key in the dabatase based on which you would like to give priority to it?

Comment: yes actually query should look like this 
db.inventory.find( { brand: { $in: [ '58e364036868441724727b8d', '58e364036868441724727b84', '58e364036868441724727b8a' ] } } )

which is reference to brand table and priority was given in that table.

Comment: So out of 3 brands, how am I going to k own during query that brand2 documents need to be on top instead of brand1&3? In there a value which can help the query to understand?

Comment: for example think brand2 is primary how can I get those data first.
I can get the priority brand before this query. there is not problem with that.

Comment: You can try $meta and sort by textScore. Check if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652975/mongodb-how-to-do-a-text-search-and-sort-by-a-date    AND  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

Comment: You can use map reduce to get desired out.
Refer this thread for similar issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740960/performing-priority-query-in-mongo

Answer (score 0):

We can get desired output by merging two queries, see steps below

1. ***find inventory products for the prioritised brand (in the question that is noted as "brand2")***

> `let arr1=await db.inventory.find( { brand: 'brand2' } );`

2. ***then find inventory products for the remaining brands (i.e. "brand1" and "brand3")***

> `let arr2=await db.inventory.find( { brand: { $ne: "brand2" } } );`

3. ***merge both output arrays***

> `let finalArr = arr1.concat(arr2);`

4. ***the final array output provided by `finalArr` details inventory with the specific brand as a priority before other brands as required***