# Mongodb aggregate match query with priority on full match

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am attempting to do a mongodb regex query on a field. I'd like the query to prioritize a full match if it finds one and then partials afterwards.

For instance if I have a database full of the following entries.

```
{
   "username": "patrick"
},
{
   "username": "robert"
},
{
   "username": "patrice"
},
{
   "username": "pat"
},
{
   "username": "patter"
},
{
   "username": "john_patrick"
}
```

And I query for the username 'pat' I'd like to get back the results with the direct match first, followed by the partials. So the results would be ordered ['pat', 'patrick', 'patrice', 'patter', 'john_patrick'].

Is it possible to do this with a mongo query alone? If so could someone point me towards a resource detailing how to accomplish it?

Here is the query that I am attempting to use to perform this.

```
db.accounts.aggregate({ $match : 
{ 
    $or : [ 
        { "usernameLowercase" : "pat" },
        { "usernameLowercase" : { $regex : "pat" } }
    ] 
} })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [performing priority query in mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740960/performing-priority-query-in-mongo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your precise example, this could be accomplished in the following way - if your real world scenario is a little bit more complex you may hit problems, though:

```
db.accounts.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "username": /pat/i // find all documents that somehow match "pat" in a case-insensitive fashion
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "exact": { 
            $eq: [ "$username", "pat" ] // add a field that indicates if a document matches exactly
        },
        "startswith": { 
            $eq: [ { $substr: [ "$username", 0, 3 ] }, "pat" ] // add a field that indicates if a document matches at the start
        }

    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "exact": -1, // sort by our primary temporary field
        "startswith": -1 // sort by our seconday temporary
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "exact": 0, // get rid of the "exact" field,
        "startswith": 0 // same for "startswith"
    }
}])
```

Another way would be using `$facet` which may prove a bit more powerful by enabling more complex scenarios but slower (several people here will hate me, though, for this proposal):

```
db.accounts.aggregate([{
    $facet: { // run two pipelines against all documents
        "exact": [{ // this one will capture all exact matches
            $match: {
                "username": "pat"
            }
        }],
        "others": [{ // this one will capture all others
            $match: {
                "username": { $ne: "pat", $regex: /pat/i }
            }
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "result": { // merge the two arrays
            $concatArrays: [ "$exact", "$others" ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$result" // flatten the resulting array into separate documents
}, {
    $replaceRoot: { // restore the original document structure
        "newRoot": "$result"
    }
}])
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you very much dnickless.