# Mongodb match query with priority on full match

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

I am attempting to do a MongoDB regex query on a field. I'd like the query to prioritize a full match if it finds one and then partials afterwards.

With `MongoTemplate`, I have written a query which correctly performs a search without any prioritisation:

```
query.addCriteria(
    new Criteria().orOperator(
        Criteria.where("name").regex(".*" + freeText + ".*", "i"),
        Criteria.where("identifier").regex(".*" + freeText + ".*", "i")));
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733967/mongodb-aggregate-match-query-with-priority-on-full-match) solution which seems to be what I am looking for. How can I re-write this with `MongoTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

1. Create 'text index' for fields you want to search.
2. Sort by  { score: { $meta: "textScore" }. "Text search queries will compute a relevance score for each document that specifies how well a document matches the query."